# Using Java 8 lambda and Stream for information extraction

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

code:

```
List<ServiceConfig> serviceConfigList = cr.getServiceConfigs();
for (ServiceConfig ser : serviceConfigList ) {
    if (ser.getValid().equals("true")) {
        Connection.SERVICE_PORT = ser.getPort();
        Connection.SERVICE_ADDRESS = ser.getIp();
        Connection.SERVICE_URL = ser.getUri();
        connection.connect(Connection.SERVICE_ADDRESS, ser.getName() + ":" + ser.getPassword());
    }
}
```

How can I rewrite this code using Java 8 Streams and lambdas?

Comment: Could you please **rephrase** - *I have a set list, but I just want to meet the criteria of information, I want to finish by Stram .*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it for you :

```
    serviceConfigList.stream()
        .filter(ser -> ser.getValid().equals("true"))
        .forEach(ser -> {
            Connection.SERVICE_PORT = ser.getPort();
            Connection.SERVICE_ADDRESS = ser.getIp();
            // other code..
    });
```

PS : I don't have your complete code. So can't help more.

Comment: You get more robust code if you write the String literal first in comparison:
`"true".equals(ser.getValid())` because this code will not fail when `ser.getValid()` returns `null`.

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer - Yes. I was merely showing the OP a way :)

Comment: @Matthias Wimmer: that depends on the definition of “robust”. If the result of `getValid()` should never be `null`, you get more robust code by placing it first, like in the answer (`ser.getValid().equals("true")`), because you’re likely to learn earlier when that assertion does not hold. Not definitely, but on a *best-effort* basis much like the fail-fast iterators spot concurrent modifications. So it depends on the contract of `getValid()`…

Comment: @Holger - Well Yes. It depends on whether you want it to be fail safe or fail fast